# Regular expression in python to capture between everything between 2 words

Tags: python, regex

Pls consider the following:(this is stored in variable op)

```
>>> print op
sho run int lo0 | sec mtu
 ip mtu 800
R4#
```

i need to capture everything starting after "sec mtu"  and before "#"

So i tried

```
str=re.search(r'(\bsec\smtu)(\n.*){2}',op,re.M|re.I)
print str.group(1)
```

however it generates an error

please suggest an alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

```
>>> s = '''sho run int lo0 | sec mtu
...  ip mtu 800
... R4#'''
>>> re.findall('sec mtu(.*)#', s, re.DOTALL)[0]
'\n ip mtu 800\nR4'
>>> s[s.find('sec mtu')+7:s.find('#')]
'\n ip mtu 800\nR4'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=\bsec\smtu\n)(.*?)(?=#)
```

Try this.Use `re.DOTALL`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dZ1vT6/54

Answer (score 0):

You could use multiline modifier also.

```
>>> re.findall('sec mtu([^#]*)#', op, re.M)[0]
'\n ip mtu 800\nR4'
>>> m = re.findall('sec mtu([^#]*)#', op, re.M)[0]
>>> print m

 ip mtu 800
R4
>>> re.search(r'(?:\bsec\smtu)([^#]*)',op, re.M|re.I).group(1)
'\n ip mtu 800\nR4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one also it will strictly capture.

```
(sec\smtu)(?:(?!(\#|\1)).)*\#
```

This regex will capture exactly want you want.

see the DEMO: http://regex101.com/r/qL0mZ1/1